# Transparent QWebView on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I'm trying to display QWebView where the contents will have round corners, so I need transparent background in order to hide the original white corners. I'm using the "trick" I found [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/06/30/transparent-qwebview-or-qwebpage/)

This did not work for me so I added

```
this->view.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

and now it works how it is supposed to on Linux(Ubuntu) and Windows, but not Mac OS X. Mac OS X just keeps displaying black corners. I tried setting stylesheet like this

```
this->view.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;");
```

or

```
this->view.setStyleSheet("background-color: none");
```

or

```
this->view.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: transparent; }");
```

But nothing worked. Is there any way I can make that work? I'm using Qt 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by upgrading Qt from **5.0.2** to **5.1.0**. It's not optimal solution but it seems that there is a lot of regressions from **4.x** to **5.0.x**.

Comment: Glad you were able to get this working. I have yet to upgrade my projects to Qt 5.x.x. I will try and see if my tray notification widgets work in Qt 5.x.x later on.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this code:
https://github.com/pcmantinker/Tray-Notification-System/blob/master/traynotificationwidget.cpp

I made a project a while back for displaying notification widgets in the system tray across all platforms compatible with Qt.

The trick is to make nested widgets with the parent widget having no border and no background and the child widget will be your display widget which you can customize with QSS.

Here's some sample images of how it looks:
Windows 7
[image: Windows 7]
Mac OS X Lion
[image: Mac OS X Lion]
Ubuntu
[image: Ubuntu]
I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going for. I mean the "notifications" but made with html + webkit. I'll try to implement your code and let you know.

Comment: I hope that this code can be adapted for your purposes. Theoretically, if you make child widgets have a transparent background, this technique should work.

Comment: Tried your code but it did not work on Mac OS X either. Maybe it's because I was trying to make QWebView transparent, who knows.